# Java awt.canvas not clipped when inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane with a JPanel in it's viewport, a number of smaller JPanels inside that  and an awt.Canvas in each of the innermost JPanels.

When scrolling the JScrollPane to where any one of the canvasses crosses the JScrollPane's borders, the canvas draws outside the border; visibly on screen outside the JScrollPane area.

I would have expected the canvas to be clipped automatically, but apparently this is not the case. Do I have to manually set up the clipping or is there another way of having a canvas clipped at the JScrollPane borders automatically?

Comment: you have to post here code in the http://sscce.org/ form that demonstrated your issue

Comment: should work with a recent jdk version (as @mKorbel already noted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since [as of the JDK 6 update 12 and JDK7 build 19 releases](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) I would still to suggesting don't mixing AWT and Swing Components together, without most important reasons

maybe is possible to reproduce that with this code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AwtSwing {

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8, 10, 10));

    public AwtSwing() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
            Canvas cnv = new Canvas();
            JPanel panelInner = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panelInner.add(cnv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(panelInner);
        }
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JTableExample");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(panel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(150, 150);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                AwtSwing awtSwing = new AwtSwing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You were right, the problem was in mixing awt with Swing.

Extending a JPanel instead of an awt.Canvas and renaming the paint(Graphics g) method to paintComponent(Graphics g) solved the clipping issue.